# Got issue with Telegram bot aiogram

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

I ran into a problem while writing code. The essence of the bot is to send the text that was sparred to the Telegram channel. The problem is that the text that was asked looks like this:

```
async def send_article(chat_id, id_topic, title, preview_text, photo_url):
        response_text = f"<b>{title}</b>\n\n<i>{preview_text}</i>\n\n<a href='http://example.com/-t{id_topic}.0.html'>Read ALL</a>"
```

It appears in the bot itself like this:

[Screenshot from bot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cj6cE.png)

First line - bold

Second line - italic

Third line - html hyperlink

[Screenshot from channel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdbvH.png)

The code for the handler to send to the channel:

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda call: call.data.startswith('pub_'))
async def publish_article(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    id_topic = call.data[4:]
    message = call.message
    chat_id = CHANNEL_ID

    if message.photo:
        response_text = message.caption
        photo_url = message.photo[-1].file_id
    else:
        response_text = message.text
        photo_url = None

    if photo_url:
        await bot.send_photo(chat_id=chat_id, photo=photo_url, caption=response_text, parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML)
    else:
        await bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=response_text, parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML)

    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton("✅Опубликовано", callback_data="published"))
    await bot.edit_message_reply_markup(chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=message.message_id, reply_markup=markup)

    await call.answer()
```

How do I save the text formatting in the sent message?

Comment: Please read the description of a tag before using it.